# SharePoint Online / Open URL in modal

Tags: sharepoint-online, modal-dialog

I'm using SP Online with Oslo layout.
The home page has a hyperlink (i.e.`<a href="..../newform.aspx">Create Your Profile</a>`)

Is there a way open the URL in modal?

I found similar postings and tried the solution from this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/create-a-hyperlink-to-open-a-new-list-item-content-type-in-modal-view-in-sharepo) but I couldn't get it to work. Each time I published the site, the code is stripped by the system.

Similar issue when I used the solution from this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2014/09/23/create-a-link-to-display-edit-and-create-new-items-from-a-dialog-layover-in-sharepoint/#comment-13455).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the second article you posted, what order do you have the webparts? Make sure you're adding the script editor webpart on top of the content editor webpart with the hyperlink. Otherwise, your function won't load first and the link won't work.

Comment: I have it at the bottom. I'll try this now and post back.  Thanks Kelvin.

Comment: It still didn't work.  After I added the code in Script Editor and placed it on top, I inserted the following on the page `<a href='javascript:displayLayover("/Lists/Staff%20Directory/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1")'>CREATE YOUR PROFILE</a>` but after saving it, SP changed it to `<a>CREATE YOUR PROFILE</a>` - it stripped the rest.

Comment: Also make sure you have the function in the Script Editor WebPart and the hyperlink in a Content Editor Webpart or you may come across the issue with the code being stripped out.

Comment: Are you just dropping the `<a href='javascript:displayLayover("/Lists/Staff%20Directory/Ne‌​wForm.aspx?IsDlg=1")‌​'>CREATE YOUR PROFILE</a>` into the Content Editor WebPart? Make sure you're selecting the webpart and then clicking 'Edit Source' in the ribbon and dropping your link in there.

Comment: No, I do click on 'Edit Source' when I use the CEWP.  Also it worked when I created the link inside the CEWP but had to changed the link to `<a href='javascript:displayLayover("/Lists/Staff%20Directory/Item/newifs.aspx?IsDlg=1‌​")‌​'>CREATE YOUR PROFILE</a>`  Thanks you so much Kelvin!